# The round shape image is not smooth and not filling the whole circle. (android)

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am converting  rectangular shaped bitmap to rounded images but the problem is that the round shape image is not smooth and not filling the whole circle. 
The code which I am using to convert into the circle :

```
public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
    int targetWidth =(int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.prof_pic_diameter);
    int targetHeight =(int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.prof_pic_diameter);

    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, 
            targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
            ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
            (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), 
                    ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
                    Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 
            new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                    sourceBitmap.getHeight()), 
                    new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

Comment: You should include an image.

Comment: Have a look on this "Romain Guy" blog http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/comment-page-1/

Comment: @ThomasW http://imgur.com/4SfVDK6 I have uploaded the image. As you can see the image is not smooth.
Anand I was using path in place of paint but thanks for the useful link.

Answer (score 0):

Use my code instead of your. If this will be NOT true. Try to increase your `dimen` value which is increase `dpi` of bitmap.

```
public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
        int targetWidth =(int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.prof_pic_diameter);
int targetHeight =(int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.prof_pic_diameter);

        Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
                targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
        final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) {
            {
                setDither(true);
                setAntiAlias(true);
                setFilterBitmap(true);
            }
        };

        Path path = new Path();
        path.reset();
        path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
                ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
                (Math.min(((float) targetWidth),
                        ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
                Path.Direction.CCW);

        canvas.clipPath(path);

        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(scaleBitmapImage);
        bitmapDrawable.setDither(true);
        bitmapDrawable.setAntiAlias(true);
        scaleBitmapImage = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

        canvas.drawBitmap(scaleBitmapImage,
                new Rect(0, 0, scaleBitmapImage.getWidth(),
                        scaleBitmapImage.getHeight()),
                new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), paint);

        return targetBitmap;
    }
```